# Does Schwarzschild metric have cosmological horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, space-expansion, metric-tensor

Since the space is not expanding in the Schwarzschild metric does that mean that there is no [cosmological horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon)?

Also, what if the Schwarzschild metric was not asymptotically flat and we replace the familiar $(1−\frac{2GM}{r})$ for $dt^2$ and $dr^2$ by for example $(1−\frac{2GM}{r}+{r^2})$. How will this effect the cosmological horizon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, the standard [Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) is asymptotically flat and indeed the time co-ordinate $t$ is the local time of an observer infinitely removed from the black hole and sitting in this flat space and so there is no pair of points outside the black hole's event horizon which ultimately cannot causally reach or signal each other. The [de Sitter-Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric) is the appropriate concept when the cosmological constant is nonzero, and this *does* have a cosmological horizon.

Comment: What if the shwartzchild metric was not asymptotically flat and we replace the familiar $(1-\frac{2G M}{r})$ for $dt^{2}$ and $dr^{2}$ by for example $(1-\frac{2G M}{r} + r^{2})$. How will this effect the cosmological horizon? Thanks

Comment: @MrDi Aaah I see I missed a sign: you're looking at an anti de Sitter black hole, right? Then there is no cosmological horizon only the event horizon, outside which all points can ultimately signal one another.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful. Does the sign of $r^{2}$  effect whether or not there is a cosmological horizon?

Comment: @MrDi Yes indeed. Just write out the metric in a region, and if it doesn't blow up, the path integral $\tau = \int_{\Gamma[a,\,b]}\mathrm{d}s$ with $d s>0$ between any two points $a$ and $b$ along the world path $\Gamma$ joining them is a well defined, finite number - the time needed for $a$ to reach $b$ (by $a$'s clock) along this path. This tells you that any pair of points in the region can causally signal one another given enough time. This is the fundamental meaning of a horizon - one can't signal points beyond it.