# How to calculate the event horizon and the cosmological radius in a metric?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor

From reading about general relativity,  the event horizon and the cosmological radius are the radius when $f(r)=0$, in the metric
$$
ds^{2}=-f(r)dt^{2}+\frac{dr^{2}}{f(r)}+r^{2}d\Omega^{2}
$$
However, how to distinguish between these two quantities and what happens if $f(R)=0$ has only one solution $r=2M$ or when it has two solution $r=2M$ and $r=R$ where $R>2M$.

Comment: Related questions by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191013/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203541/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203977/2451

Answer (score 1):

For a spherically symmetric system there are only two possibilities for the function $f(r)$:

$$ f(r) = 1 - \frac{2a}{r} $$

$$ f(r) = 1 - br^2 $$

Though you can combine the two to get:

$$ f(r) = 1 - \frac{2a}{r} - br^2 $$

Any of these forms is a perfectly valid solution of the Einstein equations, and the exact form of $f(r)$ is determined by specifying the initial conditions. For example if we have a non-zero mass but no cosmlogical constant then $a = M$ and $b = 0$ and we get the Schwarzschild metric. If we have no mass but a non-zero cosmological constant then $a = 0$ and $b = \Lambda$ and we get a de Sitter metric. Non-zero $a$ and $b$ give the de Sitter-Schwarzschild metric.

So the existance of one or two zeros for $f(r)$ just depends on what initial conditions you specify. Specifically it requires non-zero mass and non-zero cosmological constant.

Comment: In modified $f(R)$ gravity, a solution may have one or more solutions to $f(R)$, independent of the initial conditions.

Comment: @MrDi: But your question was about GR was it not?

Comment: My question is about  how to distinguish between cosmological radius and event horizon if $f(r)=0$ has more than one solution where $f(r)$ is component of the metric. I don't think it matters whether its general relativity metric or modified gravity metric, does it?

Comment: @MrDi: I'm not sure I have grasped exactly what you're unsure of. If you're asking why solution is which then the event horizon is at the smaller value of $r$ and the cosmological horizon at the larger value of $r$. Obviously (at least I think it's obvious) the cosmological horizon cannot be inside the event horizon.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate event horizon...

1. It is the radius sphere around a black hole through which even light fails to escape
2. Therefore, light energy$(E)=mc²$
   Energy needed to escape
   i.e potential energy=$\frac{GMm}{R}$

   Therefore, equating $$mc²=\frac{GMm}{R}$$ $$C²=\frac{GM}{R}$$ $$R=\frac{GM}{c^2}$$
   Where, $M$ = mass of the black hole notsure if my logic is correct

Comment: You're off by a factor of 2.
https://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/s/Schwarzschild+Radius